# Topics I should learn for converting this Classic-ASP code into ASP.NET? Mainly SQL Server Database Access

Tags: asp.net, asp-classic

So, I have a very simple bit of ASP on my website currently, which you can check out here:  http://www.marioplanet.com/catalog.asp

Just ignore the CSS issue for now! :)

Anyway, so, I have a SQL Server table in a database, and I'm pulling some information from it to make a shopping catalog of all my products.

I was wondering if there is any need to convert this to ASP.NET, and if I should, as I'm eager to learn how, which topics of ASP.NET does this include?

I would assume handling data through a SQL Server Database Table?

Also, which ASP.NET framework is best suited for this kind of work?  For the most part, the only ASP.NET code I'm going to be using, is going to be handling data from a database.  Other than a few conditionals and what not.

Any ideas and suggestions are greatly appreciated!

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

If you are comfortable in classic ASP, I wouldn't rush to change it.

However, if I were to convert it, I would lean toward ASP.NET MVC because it is closer to  classic ASP than ASP.NET with WebForms.

There are numerous data frameworks.  I think LINQ to SQL has a lot of momentum and would be fairly easy to learn coming from a classic ASP background.

Comment: Thanks for the post, although, I really should be considered a complete Classic-ASP n00b as well, I mainly got this explained to me by one of my friends, so it's mainly his code, but I understand most of it.  In other words, it'll kind of be a fresh start no matter the direction I go! :)